# Counting unique pairs, but applying that count to all of its entries in SQL (not removing duplicates)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have a table:

```
ID  A   B
10  0   0
11  0   0
12  0   1
13  0   1
14  1   1
15  1   1
16  1   1
```

And I want my table output to be:

```
ID  A   B   A_B_COUNT
10  0   0   2
11  0   0   2
12  0   1   2
13  0   1   2
14  1   1   3
15  1   1   3
16  1   1   3
```

but with the code I have here my output looks like this

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS A_B_COUNT
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B

ID  A   B   A_B_COUNT
10  0   0   2
12  0   1   2
14  1   1   3
```

Any way I can create an sql query to is like my top table vs the one I make currently
Using: 10.5.5-MariaDB

Comment: Which MySQL/Mariadb version?

Comment: Using 10.5.5-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by a, b) as a_b_count
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it to work. I don't use sql too often so I didn't know about the partition by functionality. Thank you!

Comment: @mike_gundy123 . . . Window functions are very handy functions -- if you are going to continue to use SQL, you might want to review what they do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select e.A, e.B, c.cnt as A_B_COUNT
from entries e
  join (
    select A, B, count(*) as cnt
    from entries
    group by A, B
  ) as c
where e.A=c.A and e.B=c.B
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jk6RfgeBFMxHiwTFxn7yrH/0).

Comment: This does work thank you! But I will be accepting the other answer since their query is more concise and I was introduced to over partition by thanks to it. Still thank you for answering!